# Implementing Scala Data Structure to Mimic Collection

Tags: scala, data-structures, collections, functional-programming

I'm attempting to build a data structure in Scala which mimics a collection by providing an ordered sequence corresponding to a range of values, a base state, and a mapper function which will calculate the desired result at a given value within the range.

The basic construction should look something like this:

```
class MappedRange[A,B,T](rng: IndexedSeq[T], z: A)(mapper: (T, A) => B) {
    private val cache = new mutable.HashMap[T, B]

    def apply(t: T): Option[B] = 
        if rng.contains(t) Some(cache.getOrElseUpdate(t, mapper(t, z)))
        else None
}
```

where a possible (contrived) use-case of this would look something like this:

```
val mapped = new MappedRange((1 to 100), ("a", "b"))
    ((i, z) => if (i % 2 == 0) z._1 else z._2 + i)

// mapped(5) => Some("b5")
// mapped(10) => Some("a")
// mapped(101) => None
```

This is all perfectly straightforward until I try to build this in such a way that it can implement many of the methods defined on `Traversable`, `map` in particular. A naive implementation would yield a result equivalent to to the following:

```
val fn = (i, z) => if (i % 2 == 0) z._1 else z._2 + i 
val mapped = new MappedRange((1 to 100), ("a", "b"))(f)

val g = _.toVector
mapped.map(g) 
// => new MappedRange(mapped.rng, mapped.base)((i, z) => g(f(i, z)))
```

I have read the documentation regarding Builders, `CanBuildFrom`, and the Scala 2.8 collections API, but I am at a loss as to how to use these patterns in this particular application. Specifically, I need to build this in such a way that

> - The *"collection"* is referentially transparent
> - Methods like `map` and `filter` will return new instances of `MappedRange` or its various subclasses
> - *Most* of the `Traversable` methods will be implementable, likely using `map`